# How to stop android system and launch a particular application in Android

Tags: android, embedded-linux, init, bionic

I have written an application in C, statically linked without using any android services or framework. It just uses API provided by kernel and libc. I want to stop all android services, framework and just launch my application when some event occurs. Is there a way to modify android's init.rc to do this?

Note: I am modifying AOSP so modifying any part of android is possible.

Comment: Please clarify the desired outcome. When your application is running it should be the only process left on the system? So no mediaserver, no wpa_supplicant, no rild, ...? What about init itself?

Comment: Yes. It should be the only app running.

Answer (score 0):

The zygote process (app_process binary in system/bin) needs to be removed from init.rc or just renamed or similar.

I haven't tried this myself but thought about it  before and googled, found the interesting link about it again:
http://vinnysoft.blogspot.se/2009/12/zygote-system-process.html

Seems to be the same still:
http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2132607

Answer (score 0):

Add your native application as a service in init.rc and remove all other serivces in init.rc. and look at the init code in system/core/init/ hope this helps

Comment: Switching between Android and my application should be possible by rebooting or some other method. So this method is not suitable I think.